# Rails in production is not finding my assets in the public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a really weird bug, a few hours after i start rails in production it stops being able to locate my assets. The weirdest thing is that i can "fix" by starting in development and then  production works for a couple of hours and the cycle repeats.  Here is a picture of my console log
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxmoZ.png).

I have a docker container that runs the app in production and there it works.

At first i thought it was from my docker so i tried removing it but it had no connection. I tried fixing the pathing but that breaks it even more. Here is my project in github if that is of any need (https://github.com/Bog2G/PollSite)

Comment: What rails version are you using Are you using an esbuild script in package.json Maybe you can run the script

Comment: Im on rails  7. Im not using esbuild.

Comment: So if the server is unable to find your assets could it be that there is something else in that machine messing up with the files our find you verify that the files were still in the container? Maybe the container's file systems gets cleaned up. How come it gets fixed when you start your server in development mode?

Comment: Are you compiling the assets? I have a Rails app on render.com and these are the configs:


Build command

`bundle install; bundle exec rake assets:clean; bundle exec rake assets:precompile; bundle exec rake db:migrate;`

Start command:

`bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`

Comment: Yes I’m compiling them, I ended up fixing the issue by commenting out config.public_file_server.enabled line in my production.rb file. I think it wasn’t’ treating my assets as static files.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the line `config.public_file_server.enabled` in the production configuration. For me, setting it to true fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your production configuration

```
config.assets.compile = true 
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

Another option is

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = false
```

or call this command on production during deployment

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

Comment: I had tried all of this but it turned out it was a problem with how rails ( for an unknown reason) was treating my assets.

Comment: did you try `npm install` or `yarn install` ?

Comment: `config.assets.compile = true` will load assets from the asset pipeline and is not a viable approach for a production environment since multiple http calls can be made, slowing it down.  See https://itecnote.com/tecnote/r-config-assets-compiletrue-in-rails-production-why-not/